# Hotlinking images

Tags: discussion

I linked to an image in [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144816/32999).

Someone edited the answer to directly show the image.  But I've always been told that hotlinking images like that was bad form.  Is there an official site policy?

Comment: Gah. NSFL. Cannot unsee.

Comment: Do downvotes here mean that the question isn't appropriate for meta?

Comment: (For anyone scared off by Reg's comment, it is literally just a picture of a kid making a funny face, exacerbated by a prominent eyebrow.  Not in anyway NSFL.)

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean "I disagree" at best, and nothing at all at worst. That's why they have no effect on your rep. Feel free to ignore. As to the picture, I actually do mean what I said. I really do want to move to the parallel universe in which I have not seen it. And from there, to the parallel universe where there's no photography, children, eyebrows, or myself. Just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that hotlinking is discouraged. Links are better than hotlinking; however, your links will be subject to the vagaries of the internet, and *will* go away with time.

If you want to make the images link-rot-proof (well, as link-rot-proof as reasonably feasible), you can upload them - StackExchange uses Imgur.com to store what you upload.

The default for uploaded images is to embed them in the post, but that will send poor RegDwigнt scrambling to find the brain bleach. So the best of both worlds (link-rot-proof, but people can choose whether to view the images or not) is to upload the image, but then edit out the exclamation mark from the image markdown code, i.e. instead of

```
![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/123abc.jpg
```

you'd have

```
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/123abc.jpg
```

(The latter is markdown syntax for a link.)

Comment: "If you want to make the images link-rot-proof (well, as link-rot-proof as reasonably feasible), you can upload them - StackExchange uses Imgur.com to store what you upload. " -- Well no, I can't.  It isn't my image to copy.

Comment: @starwed: What I usually do is save the picture to my computer, modify it so it's as relevant as possible (crop out parts that aren't important, reduce the size to the minimum that still gets my point across, etc.), and then upload *that*.